# IntelliJ + single unit test

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse I click on a single file / Test case, choose "Run as Junit Tes" and that's it.
In IntelliJ I have to create a new configuration for a "class based test". Effort seems much higher than in Eclipse...

I'm missing something or is this really the solution IJ provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run any class that has methods annotated with @Test merely by...running it (either through the menu, right-clicking, or using the shortcut keys; for Mac, that would be Command + Shift + F10).

This will automatically create the run profile for that test.

Comment: Thanks, missed that - looks cool. But is there something similar for the whole file with, say 10 test-cases in it?

Comment: Perform the same run action outside of the scope of any method annotated with @Test, and it will execute every test in the file.